# What are the brown stains on my ceiling?

Tags: paint

It’s my first time renting and wanted to know what those brown stuff on the ceiling is.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Water stains.  If from above or someone tossed water up, but usually from above.

Comment: [Many related questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Adiy.stackexchange.com+brown+stain+on+ceiling)

Answer (score 0):

Are they new or have they been there since you moved in?

Usually, the culprit is water dripping from the other side or possible mold growth in the ceiling. Could be a possible scuff mark that was missed in paint job.